# Understanding PagerAdapter in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

1. What does the method `isViewFromObject(View v,Object obj)` do ? Almost everytime I have implemented it , it has been like below:-

   ```
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
     return (view==object);
    }
   ```
2. Considering that I am passing in String urls to a PagerAdapter , and I instantiate the view and add it to the container dynamically using `instantiateItem()` , how would I provide an implementation for `getItemPosition(Object object)`. I understand that the object passed to `getItemPosition` is the view returned from `instantiateItem`. Of course I can add some tag to the views instantiated in `instantiateItem()`, but is there any other way of getting the position of the`String` passed into the `PagerAdapter`.

Please let me know if I am not clear, so that I can post again if needed.

Comment: I have kind of had the same question. I'm not 100% sure but I was of the impression that it would help in the cases where a given view can be recycled to represent multiple items. So this is your chance to basically tell the viewpager, Hey I meant to do that, and please don't assume this view is garbage. In the cases when I have done this wrong, the view just disappears and is ejected from the pager. So after remove item is called, if views still exist that were associated with the page. I.e. view.getTag().getClass().isAssignableFrom(object.getClass()); where object is some enum type or smtg